# Sencha Cmd 5 and ST 2.4 "build package" bad result

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-cmd5

I've been using sencha Cmd since its release and after every update I face some new issues.

Last one, using sencha Cmd Sencha Cmd v5.0.2.270 and sencha touch 2.4, I cant even produce a valid package build.

actual build using cmd 5 and sencha touch 2.4 (not even good build folder):
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35041662/build2.4/bad.PNG

previous build (the one I need):
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35041662/build2.4/good.PNG

After the "sencha app build package", I deploy it into a "local server" (something phonegap alike) and when I try to run the project, it keeps me asking to reload the app due to an change in one of the app's javascript and never achieve to run.

alert Message:
"Requested: '[...]/js/appverse.js seems to have been changed. Attempt to refresh the application?"

Btw the production an package build generate a cache.appcache file and the app keeps me asking for reload, in previous version of cmd those files didn't exist.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's no longer supported as from 5.0.2.270.

I had the same problem and the only way to solve was, to install the npm cordova within Sencha Touch (sencha cordova init).

After that I can now use the app.cordova.www folder.

Comment: Thank you, I get to the same conclusion but using phonegap, same thing, disapointing however since I dont use Phonegap/cordova.